# failed request to api Slim frame

Tags: android, mysql, api, slim

I build webservice using Slim Framework from http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/

I check API from chrome, and everything works correct. But I don't know how I should use this on android app.
I try do this:

```
// Creating HTTP client
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
// Creating HTTP Post
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(MY_API_URL);

// Building post parameters
// key and value pair
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Name_"));
                        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "email@email.com"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pass"));
// Url Encoding the POST parameters
try {
   httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
// writing error to Log
e.printStackTrace();
}

// Making HTTP Request
try {
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

// writing response to log
   Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
// writing exception to log
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// writing exception to log
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [**retrofit**](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) instead of `DefaultHTTPClient`.